# Side by side subfigures in lyx

Tags: lyx, subfloats

I am using lyx and want to put two figures side by side. I could do it by inserting two minipages separated by a \hfill inside a float but it only allows me to use separate captions rather than subcaptions (I want it to be labeled as fig 1a, fig 1b). Also by inserting float inside a float, the 2nd figure appeared below the first one rather than in side. Any tips would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The better approach I found, was to use subfigures (especially when you want to refer to subfigures as `1a` or `1b`. From the [LaTeX FAQ](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/FiguresSideBySide):

- Insert→Float→Figure
- Again, Insert→Float→Figure (this inserts a "subfigure float" into the
  float)
- Put the cursor right next to the subfloat
- Insert→Formatting→Horizontal Space→Horizontal Fill or Ctrl- ->
  right-click on space -> select "Horizontal Fill" (to insert a
  stretchable horizontal space)
- Insert→Float→Figure (this inserts another "subfigure float")
- In each subfloat:add the graphics and edit the caption
- To insert a vertical space, Insert→Formatting→Vertical Space→DefSkip.

Or if you could just use this code (this is LyX syntax; not LaTeX) from what I created (you may have to right click on the images and adjust the width % of the images):

```
\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename images/Fig2_1.png
    scale 30

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Name1
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:label1"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset space \hfill{}
\end_inset


\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename images/Fig2_2.png
    scale 30

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Name2
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:Name2"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset VSpace defskip
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename images/Fig2_3.png
    scale 30

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Name3
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:Name3"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset space \hfill{}
\end_inset


\begin_inset Float figure
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename images/Fig2_4.png
    scale 30

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Name3
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:Name3"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Caption for figure
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "fig:FigureLabel"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset

 
\end_layout
```

For doing the same thing in pure LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{center}
\subfigure[Name1]{\includegraphics[width=1.625in]{images/Fig2_1.png}}
\subfigure[Name2]{\includegraphics[width=1.625in]{images/Fig2_2.png}}
\subfigure[Name3]{\includegraphics[width=1.625in]{images/Fig2_3.png}}
\subfigure[Name4]{\includegraphics[width=1.625in]{images/Fig2_4.png}}
\end{center}
\caption{Caption for figure}
\label{figureLabel}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem, I found a solution which apparently worked for me in lyx:

1. Insert> Float > Figure
2. Insert > Box > Frameless.
3. Right click on minipage and go to settings. Set width to 45 column width%
4. Click right next to the minipage (not inside). Go to Insert> Formatting> Horizontal space and select horizontal fill in spacing.
5. Repeat step2 and add graphics in both minipages.
6. Go to Document> Settings > LaTex Preamble and add \usepackage{subcaption}
7. Inside each minipage, Insert tex code \subcaption{Your
   subcaption here}

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above to work. A (low-brow?) way to do this is with a table, ie to make:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{image1} & \includegraphics[width=7cm]{image2}\tabularnewline
(a) & (b)\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}\caption{foiw}
\end{figure}
```

For that I just

1. Insert Figure
2. Insert 2x2 tabular
3. Insert Graphics inside each cell in the top row
4. Write `(a)` and `(b)` in the lower row cells (or longer captions if you like)
5. Select all four cells and turn off all borders
6. Select the tabular and right-click and change paragraph to centered

With this, you can add a referencing label to the overall figure, but not separately to each subfigure. You would just use, e.g. `Figure~\ref{myfig}(a)`